# Linking from HTML code to specific bookmark/page in PDF using FOXIT (or other)

Tags: html, pdf, plugins, hyperlink, foxit

I'm trying to link from an HTML page to a PDF file. I'd like to add links to specific pages, using urls such as 
http://www.mydomain.com/some-pdf-file.pdf#nameddest=somebookmark
or
http://www.mydomain.com/some-pdf-file.pdf#page=7

This works fine in not-so-beloved Adobe Acrobat Reader (at least using FF plugin).
Is there a way to make it work under Foxit too?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the only thing I found is: http://forums.foxitsoftware.com/showthread.php?p=37155. Hope that helps.